# AlarmManager does not trigger while changing the time

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In my application I am displaying notifications to the user as per their custom time. I am triggering `alarmmanager` in my main class and calling the notification `service` class as `pendingIntent` through `alarmmanager`.

If the user did not change the device time means, `alarmmanager` is firing and the notification `service` is working fine and I am getting the notifications.

Consider the following case:

If the user sets the device time greater then the current time, everything is working fine and notification is working. If not, the user set the time lesser then the device current time, then the `alarmmanager` does not fire the `pendingIntent`. So I am unable to get the notifications.

In detail

Device current time : 10 am
Notification time: 11 am
Device time change to : 11 am
Notification : yes

Device current time : 10 am
Notification time: 9 am
Device time change to : 9 am
Notification : No

Why this is happening?

Changing the device time lesser than the current time does not fires the `alarm manager`.. why?

How to overcome this?

Comment: Use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see the state of your alarm after your system time changes.

Comment: AlarmManager does not handle time change. You should listen action for time change and then re-schedule the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to store all set alarms in database, then create a BroadcastReceiver which will listen for ACTION_TIME_CHANGE action. When user changes time it will be triggered. Then create a IntentService which will be responsible for resetting alarms. In this service class:

Read db and identify all passed alarms.
Cancel passed alarms
Set alarms for next day
Your code may look like as below:
In your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_TIME_CHANGE"/>
```

and below activities:

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeChangedReceiver" android:enabled="true">
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Create class "TimeChangedReceiver" inside of which:

```
public class TimeChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if("android.intent.action.TIME_SET".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, RestartAlarmsService.class);
        ComponentName service = context.startService(i);
    }

}
```

}

Create "RestartAlarmsService" class inside of which:

```
public class RestartAlarmsService extends IntentService {

public RestartAlarmsService() {
    super("RestartAlarmsService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    // read db here
    // then cancel passed alarms
    // reset them to next day
}
```

}

You can find many tutorials on how to use Databases and implement it in your code. Hope my answer is somehow helpful.